# Looking for methods to calculate $\lim\sup a_n$ using rudin's definition. Also looking for exercises.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

I've been delving in to baby rudin for the past few weeks and am now trying to finish up chapter 3. However, though I understand the definition he gives for $\lim\sup a_n$, I find it very hard to actually do calculations with it. My non-formal understanding:

*If we let A be the set with the limitpoint of all possible subsequences of $\{a_n\}$, then $\lim\sup a_n$ is the supremum of A.*

Which is a solid definition, but in order to calculate it - if I'm able to do it at all - I find that I'm having to find the supremum and infinum by looking at the way the series progresses and "eyeballing" a solution. This gets especially problematic when trying to use the ratio and root tests.

So I'm looking for methods to actually start thinking about this in a more practical sense to actually start calculating them.

For reference, this is Rudin's definition:

*Given a sequence $\{s_n\}$ of real numbers, let $E$ be the set of numbers $x$ (in the extended real number system) such that $s_{n_k} \to x$ for some subsequence $\{s_{n_k}\}$. This set contains all subsequential limits ..., plus possibly the numbers $+\infty$, $-\infty$. We now ... put 
$$s^{*} = \sup E,$$
$$s_{*} = \inf E.$$
The numbers $s^{*}$, $s_{*}$ are called the upper and lower limits of $\{s_n\}$; we use the notation 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup s_n = s^{*}, \, \, \, \lim_{n \to \infty} \inf s_n = s_{*}.$$*

Comment: I always think about lim-sup as follows: Start with a_1; now you will skip as many (finite though) items in search of a bigger value. Say you find that a_2, a_3, ... are smaller than a_1, but then a_10 is larger than a_1. Then keep searching for the next big value, skipping some items as you scan the sequence. So, in other words, you move along the sequence cherry-picking the bigger ones. The sequence you pick will converge to the lim-sup. Think of the sequence as a chain of mountain peaks, then you jump from high top to the net high peak, ignoring the low peaks in process.

Comment: Don't know whether it helps, but you can also define $\limsup a_n$ as the limit of the monotone sequence $(b_n)_n$ defined by $b_n:=\sup_{k\geq n}a_k$. Likewise you can define $c_n:=\inf_{k\geq n}a_k$. Then $\liminf a_n=\lim c_n$ and $a_n\in [c_n,b_n]\supseteq[c_{n+1},b_{n+1}]$ for each $n$. The setsequence $[c_n,b_n]$ gets smaller and smaller and the intersection gives $[c,b]$ where $c=\liminf a_n$ and $b=\limsup a_n$.

Comment: @Behnam That's actually helpful! But it doesn't seem entirely trivial, for what if no such $a_i$ exists? Do you happen to know a proof for that system?

Comment: @drhab Nah, sadly that doesn't help me find a good way to start calculating them. (At least not from a cursory glance.)

Comment: I meant to add: You have to pick some term every so often. For instance if you have a decreasing sequence, then you have no choice but to pick a decreasing sequence. Can you give example of sequence for which you wanna find lim sup?

Comment: As for proof, one considers the sequence $b_n=\sup \{a_n, a_{n+1},...}$, i.e. supremum of the set that consists of n'th term and above of a-sequence. Either this is infinity, in which case lim sup of a_i is infinity, otherwise, b_n is a decreasing sequence (sup of a smaller set is smaller). thus, b_n has a limit. One shows that this limit is lim sup a_i. If for each b_n, we subtract 1/n, then there exists a member of the set $\{a_n,a_{n+1},...\}$ such that $b_n>a_{m_n}>b_n-1/n$. The subsequence $a_{m_n}$ of of a_n converges to lim b_n which is lim sup of a_n.

Comment: The only example I currently have is quite convoluted; specifically, if we know that $\sum a_n $ converges, show that $\sum \frac\sqrt {a_n}n $ converges. I wanted to attempt the root test, so: $\lim \sup \sqrt[n]{\frac\sqrt{a_n}n} $.  Apologies if the tex isn't working well, I'm writing this on my phone.